# Join one row from a table with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, optimization, count, query-optimization

This is a question regarding queries in mysql. As an example let’s use a system that tracks the selling of cars. There is table with `salespersons`, a table of `sales` and a table that links the two. Most of the time each sale has only one person associated with it. But sometimes multiple persons are associated with a sale.

```
Table sales
id | carId | date
---+-------+-----------
1  | 2     | 11-01-2011
2  | 8     | 11-02-2011
3  | 5     | 11-05-2011

Table link
personId | saleId
---------+-------
2        | 1 
2        | 2 
1        | 3
2        | 3

Table salesperson
id | name  | age
---+-------+----
1  | Barry | 25
2  | Sara  | 32
```

To retrieve the data I want to show the information of each sale in a webpage. But when multiple persons are associated with a sale it becomes problematic. I have tried applying the query below in my code, after which the PHP handles the exception of when multiple persons are associated with one sale, but due to the length of the sales table the query below takes too much time to run:

```
SELECT count(personId) as amount, carId, date
FROM link 
JOIN salesperson ON link.personId = salesperson.id  
JOIN sales ON sales.id = link.saleId
GROUP BY link.saleId
```

Is there a more efficient query that can be used? By the way indexing of the table is already done.

Comment: What data do you want to retrieve? Is it sales per salesperson?

Comment: i want to show a list of sales with the connected sales person(s)

Comment: have u used any index in link??

Comment: yes one on personID and one on saleID

Comment: I would double ChrisBD, and reask what you want to retrieve. If you group by saleid, then `name` and `age` of the sales people do not make sense anymore.

Comment: And are not you going to apply a condition on the query (WHERE saleId = something), since the current result of the query will hardly be observable and printed on a page. This may cause revision of your indexing strategy.

Comment: We dont have a indexing strategy. I removed name and age your right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then it is just:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
    amount, carId, date
FROM (
    SELECT saleId, count(*) as amount
    FROM link
    GROUP BY saleId
    ORDER BY NULL) as amounts
JOIN sales ON sales.id = amounts.saleId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the right indices to the tables? I don't know how big your tables are, but I can't imagine it should be much of a problem.

Also, what result are you trying to get from your query? It seems like you are trying to get all sales and then count how many sales people were involved?

Comment: No all sales with the sales people. The Table link is more than 350.000 rows

Comment: Have you put indices on the table (are you sure you have done it correctly)? What type have you used for the columns?

Answer (score 0):

You query looks OK, but your group by is a little odd...
Try the standard approach of grouping by all non-aggregate columns, like this:

```
SELECT carId, date, name, age, count(personId) as amount
FROM link 
JOIN salesperson ON salesperson.id = link.personId
JOIN sales ON sales.id = link.saleId
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: I have never heard of 'GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;' but the query takes 28 secs

Comment: `GROUP BY 1,2,3,4` is short for "group by column #1, column #2, column #3, column #4", in this case identical to coding `GROUP BY carId, date, name, age`. I much prefer the brevity of this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem may be that you are using the link table as your base table and the database optimisation of the query isn't good.
Try:

```
SELECT count(sp.personId) as amount, s.carId as carId, s.date as date, sp.name as name, sp.age as age  
FROM sales as s
JOIN link as l ON s.id = l.saleId
JOIN salesperson as sp ON l.personId = sp.id  
ORDER BY l.saleId
```

Comment: this will count the number of rows in the product and output the first row =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with the performance aspect avoid using Joins especially in mysql. 
read this article demonstrating the efficient coding techniques 
http://phpadvent.org/2011/a-stitch-in-time-saves-nine-by-paul-jones

For your problem in first query select sales ID
in second query select personID from links table 
in third query select select all persons from person table

As mentioned in the article use IN clause while passing a query. it looks little lengthy in coding but is much efficient than using join on table with 15k+ rows